# sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

Tags: sudo, root, chown

I am trying to run the following command:

```
$ echo "My username is: `whoami`"
My username is: d
$ sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/node_modules
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

I don't understand what the problem is because root is uid 0:

```
$ id -u root
0
```

And the setuid seem fine:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 4755 root 155008 Feb 10  2014 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Setuid bit is *not* set. If it were, the permissions would have an `s` instead of the first `x`:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/sudo 
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 155008 Feb 11  2014 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Try using `pkexec` to set it correctly:

```
pkexec chmod a=rx,u+ws /usr/bin/sudo
```

Though I doubt that's the only problem you are going to have.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that one - could have saved me grief the other day!

Comment: Oh! Look! I can upvote twice!

Comment: i got this "pkexec must be setuid root" what should i do?

Comment: @user12158726 then you're much worse off and will need to reboot and use recovery shell, or use a live USB, to fix permissions.

Comment: pkexec must be setuid root

Answer (score 2):

Login with root (su) and run the following command

```
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Answer (score 1):

Cant run sudo type

```
$ sudo -l
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

shows error **usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set**

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/sudo 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 136808 Jul  4 07:37 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Its beacuase of Permission issue

```
 $ su
 Password: <type your root password>
```

Switch to root user and run the command

```
# pkexec chmod a=rx,u+ws /usr/bin/sudo
```

Then check it by typing from the user

```
$sudo -l
```

it Works fine for me

Cheers....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my **WSL on Windows**:

Exit bash. Run via elevated CMD Terminal:

```
lxrun /setdefaultuser root
```

Start bash. Run the command from Thirumal

```
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Exit Bash. Run via elevated CMD Terminal:

```
lxrun /setdefaultuser <Your Original User>
```

Start Bash

Answer (score 0):

1 - on an elevated CMD change default user to root:

```
ubuntu1804.exe config --default-user root
```

2 - open bash (zsh in my case) and change ownership:

```
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

3 - on an elevated CMD change default user back to my username

```
ubuntu1804.exe config --default-user [my_username]
```